# Sql azure - monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-sql-database

I have a problem with connect to database MS SQL Azure in monotouch. To a simple database MS SQL I can connect - all successfully opens a connection request and is, but to MS SQL Azure i have error: SSL encryption for data sent between client and server is not implemented.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:asz59ug1bl.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Mymd;User ID=myuser@asfe41241;Password=MyPwd;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=True;"))
            {
            connection.Open(); }
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Trusted_Connection parameter shall always be set to FALSE for SQL Azure connections. Change this and try again.

Comment: @astaykov - that comment should be moved to an answer.

Comment: @David short responses are auto-moved by SO to comments

Comment: How about adding the [MSDN page link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx) along with the answer? I'd think that would be fine, no?

Answer (score 4):

a potential issue is your "Trusted_Connection=true" in your connection string. For SQL Azure, it is always adviced that users set FALSE for this parameter. You can check out following resources for more information:

- Official MSDN [Guidelines for Connecting to SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx).
- [TechNet article for SQL Azure connection security](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connection-security.aspx)
- connectionstrings.com [page for SQL Azure](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure)

You may also want to add "TrustServerCertificate=false" to your connection string.

Comment: Wow - such a thorough, non-comment-length answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access SQL Azure with mono, at least with 2.10.

Write a web or worker role on Windows Azure to provide access to your SQL Azure database and yeah, it will cost you $15 / month to do that - or use normal .NET on a windows machine and it will work fine.

If anyone has made it work. I am eager to know which connection string has worked.